# amp-live-list support updated content and deleted posts?

Tags: amp-html

amp-live-list couldn't get updated content and deleted posts.

### How do we reproduce the issue?

hit certain endpoint and returns a json array of posts. but if the json got deleted some posts / updated content. 
couldn't see the post get updated.

### does amp supports updated content and deleted posts ?

Comment: yeah... it suppots.
is it okay to delete the question?

Comment: Yes, you can delete this post.